# Name for object that gives enough information to compare morphisms

Tags: category-theory

In some categories, there is an object $X$ such that for any $f, g : Y \to Z$, $f = g$ if $f \circ h = g \circ h$ for all $h : X \to Y$.

- In the category of sets, any terminal object works
- In the category of groups, $\mathbb{Z}$ works (since for any $y \in Y$, we can make a homomorphism $h : \mathbb{Z} \to Y$ by letting $h(1) = y$)
- In the category of graphs with no isolated vertices, the graph $\cdot \to \cdot$ works (since we have a homomorphism for each edge of $Y$)

What is this kind of object called?

Comment: Compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism

Comment: Here I'm saying that $f = g$ if *for all* morphisms $h : X \to Y$, $f \circ h = g \circ h$, not just some epimorphism. For example, $X = \{*\}$ works for sets, yet there are no epimorphisms from $\{*\}$ to some other set in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a generator of the category. The dual notion is that of cogenerator.

You can also have a set of objects that all together act as you suggest, and then they're called a set of generators (of course if you have a category with products with surjective projections and a *set* of generators, then you also have a generator - as Arnaud D. pointed out, what you really need is a cone with epimorphic projections)

Comment: I think you mean "coproducts" in your parenthetical remark.

Comment: @ArnaudD. No I did mean product : if you have $f\neq g$, then it is witnessed on one of the factors, so you project onto this factor and then to $Y$. Coproduct won't work, because you might not get a morphism from each of the factors

Comment: Oh right. I was a bit naive...

Comment: But come to think of it what you're suggesting only works if all the projections of the product are epimorphisms, which is not always true. In fact your reasoning would work for any cone of epimorphisms above all the generators, since you don't use the universal property.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You are of course correct, I wrote that too quickly (I was thinking in some nice context such as abelian categories, where you can actually take the coproduct and have some split "projections", which are thus obviously epi)

Comment: @ArnaudD. Note, though, that if products exist, and if there is a cone with epic projections, then the projections of the product are epic